# Auto create subpath exports for typescript package

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, package.json

Given I have the following typescript package structure, with a src folder containing an inputs folder and a buttons folder (there would be more folders). Example structure below:

```
 common-package/
       src/
          inputs/
             TextBox.tsx
             RadioButton.tsx
             index.ts
          buttons/
             PrimaryButton.tsx
             SecondaryButton.tsx
             index.ts
          index.ts
```

With a typescript package how can I allow barrel import with the file I want to use in another repo using the built package as well as direct sub paths for each component.

Examples:

```
import { TextBox, RadioButton } from 'common-package'
```

and

```
import TextBox from 'common-package/TextBox'
import RadioButton from 'common-package/RadioButton'
```

I have looked into `exports` and `typeVersions` in the `package.json` but this is extremely manual to have to create these individually and im looking for an automatic way to export all components by name after the package name. I dont want to have inputs or button folder naming in the module resolution path.